# Sencha Touch 2 MVC list event wiring

Tags: model-view-controller, list, events, sencha-touch

I am trying to follow this Sencha Touch 2 MVC example: https://github.com/FrancisShanahan/SenchaTouch2MVCHelloworld.

The onStationSelect event does not work:

```
Ext.define('HelloWorld.controller.Home', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',   
views: ['Home', 'SimpleList'],
stores: ['Stations'],
// These "refs" will generate "getters" for each of the view component instances
// e.g. getBottomField and getStationList
refs: [{
        selector: 'carousel > panel > #bottomInput',
        ref: 'bottomField'
        },
        {
        selector: 'carousel > list', 
        ref: 'stationList'
        }
],
init: function() {
    console.log('Init home controller');
    // Start listening for events on views
    this.control({
        // example of listening to *all* button taps
        'button': { 'tap': function () {
                    console.log('Every button says Hello world');
                } 
            },
        // Example of listening by an explicit id
        '#firstButton': { 'tap': function () {
                    console.log('Only the button with id=firstButton says Hello');
                    alert(this.getBottomField().getValue());
                } 
            }           
    });
},

onLaunch: function() {
    console.log('onLaunch home controller');
    // The "getter" here was generated by specifying the 
    // stores array (above)
    var stationsStore = this.getStationsStore();  

    stationsStore.load({
        callback: this.onStationsLoad,
        scope: this
    });
},

onStationsLoad: function() {
    console.log('onStationsLoad home controller');
    // get a reference to the view component
    var stationsList = this.getStationList();
    // do something
},

onStationSelect: function(selModel, selection) {
    // Fire an application wide event
    this.application.fireEvent('stationstart', selection[0]);
},
});
```

What is wrong with the event wiring here?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The missing part was:

```
this.control({
    'list' : {
        itemtap : this.onStationSelect
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of this post and [the tutorial 'How to Create a Sencha Touch 2 App, Part 1'](http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/) helped me understand `control` and `refs` in a controller better.  Thought I would share.